# Reading XLSX into MFC Application

Tags: c++, excel, csv, mfc, xlsx

I am needing to read in data from an XLSX document into my MFC application.
It has been working fine however I now have the requirement of reading in foreign language characters and they are getting lost.

Example value which I need to read in are:

Лице и тяло

Мама и бебе

Currently I first convert the xlsx to a csv using the following script which I found online

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo \"Error!Please specify the source path and the destination.Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim numRows
Dim numCols
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
Set oWorksheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
oWorksheet.Activate
oWorksheet.Cells.Replace ",", "" 
Dim celltxt
celltxt = oWorksheet.Cells(1,1).Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, \"Date\") Then
    For count = 13 to 17
        oWorksheet.Columns(count).NumberFormat = "0"
    Next
Else
    For count = 1 to 4
        oWorksheet.Columns(count).NumberFormat = "0"
    Next
End If
numRows = oWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
numCols = oWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Dim BinaryStream
Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
BinaryStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText
BinaryStream.Open
For r = 1 To numRows
    s = ""
    For c = 1 To numCols
        s = s & oWorksheet.Cells(r, c).Value
        If c < numCols Then
            s = s & ","
        End If
    Next
BinaryStream.WriteText s, 1
Next
BinaryStream.SaveToFile WScript.Arguments.Item(1), adSaveCreateOverWrite
BinaryStream.Close
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Once this script runs and i open the resulting csv before any further processing, the data in the csv looks fine.

Once this csv is processed by the aplication (Loaded using CRecordSet) the above values look as follows:

¦Ы¦¬TЖ¦¦ ¦¬ TВTП¦¬¦-

¦Ь¦-¦-¦- ¦¬ ¦-¦¦¦-¦¦

What I found is that if I open the csv before processing it and go to "Save As", the "Save as type" value is on "Unicode Text".
If I now overwrite the csv by saving as "CSV (Comma delimited)", then let the file process into my app, the resulting values look as follows:

TшЎх ш Є ыю

¦рьр ш схсх

and if I manually saved the csv as "CSV (MS-DOS)" and then let my app process it, the values come out correctly:

Лице и тяло

Мама и бебе

So on the one hand, I dont understand the differences and why I need the MS-DOS csv version to get my app to read in the value correctly, and secondly, I need to be able to process the data correctly without hte manually save as in between.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks alot

UPDATE:

Just to test, I changed my code (which runs the script to convert to csv) to output to a .txt instead of .csv and again the output file looks right before my application reads it in but it still imports from there into my application wrong.

Here is the output .txt contents:

```
From Date,To Date,Store ID,Store Name,Retailer,Retail Format,Region,Cluster,Market Attr 1 (Numeric),Market Attr 2 (Numeric),Market Attr 3 (Text),Market Attr 4 (Text),Market Attr 5 (Text),Product ID,EAN (Barcode),UPC (Product Code),Brand,Description,Size & Uom,Size,Uom,Supplier,Shrink Pack,Minimum Display Depth,KVI,Status,Product Height,Product Width,Product Depth,Supergroup A,Supergroup B,Category,Sub Category,Segment,Sub Segment,Product Attr 1 (Numeric),Product Attr 2 (Numeric),Product Attr 3 (Text),Product Attr 4 (Text),Product Attr 5 (Text),Sales (Value),Units (Volume),Sales at Cost,Ranging Indicator,Fact 1 (Numeric),Fact 2 (Numeric),Fact 3 (Numeric),Fact 4 (Text),Fact 5 (Text)
01/01/2014,31/01/2016,130,Maritza,Clicks,Pharmacy,Plovdiv,A Range,1.99,2.99,Attribute 3,Attribute 4,Attribute 5,1347,7612729000518,ПОЛИНЕЙЛ лечебен лак за нокти 80мг/гр 33мл,Coca Cola,ПОЛИНЕЙЛ лечебен лак за нокти 80мг/гр 33мл,330ml,330,ml,Coca Cola,6,2,1,Active,CONVERT,37,36,Лице и тяло,Медицинска козметика,Carbonated Soft Drinks,Diet,On The Go,Cans,1.99,2.99,Attribute 3,Attribute 4,Attribute 5,136.27,12,122.21,1,1.99,2.99,3.99,Yes,No
01/01/2014,31/01/2016,130,Maritza,,Pharmacy,Plovdiv,,,,,,,1349,5903263245933,СУДО крем антисептичен 125гр,,СУДО крем антисептичен 125гр,,,,,,,,,66,6,6,Мама и бебе,Козметика бебе,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
01/01/2014,31/01/2016,130,Maritza,,Pharmacy,Plovdiv,,,,,,,1381,,СПРИНЦОВКА 1МЛ ТРИСЪСТАВНА инсулинова спринцовка х 1бр,,СПРИНЦОВКА 1МЛ ТРИСЪСТАВНА инсулинова спринцовка х 1бр,,,,,,,,,198,3,1,Мама и бебе,Храни и напитки бебе,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
01/01/2014,31/01/2016,130,Maritza,,Pharmacy,Plovdiv,,,,,,,1607,8716200646536,ФРИЗОПЕП AC 400гр,,ФРИЗОПЕП AC 400гр,,,,,,,,,123,10,10,Мама и бебе,Храни и напитки бебе,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Looks like some code somewhere is losing the information that the text is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Do u mean in my c++ code? Shouldn't it be a problem regardless of the saved file type?

Comment: Somewhere, I don't know where, I'm just interpreting what your output looks like, and having seen similar before.

Comment: The problem occur when you try to convert a foreign char. I expected that your cpp program **need** a DOS format, but your converter working as platform format (windows or mac). That's why you get the char to be wrong. I think you should look up a new code for the converter. It's a common problem in csv file convert.